# Как редактировать элемент QComboBox?

Tags: qt, qcombobox

Всем,привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как  я могу отредактировать элемент из списка QComboBox? Я подумал что можно было бы обработать событие клика на какой нибудь
из элементов внутри списка, но как это сделать и можно ли вообще так делать не знаю

Comment: Насколько я помню, элементы самого QComboBox не редактирумые из интерфейса. Мб вам больше QListWidget подойдет?

Comment: Насчет сигналов, они описаны: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcombobox.html#signals Пример тех, которые относятся к выбору элементов: currentIndexChanged, currentTextChanged и activated

Comment: Дело в том что на форме уже стоит QComboBox, но пользователь хочет уметь редактировать его элементы, а не нужные удалить. Я хотел добавить список действий при клике на элемент на правую кнопку мыши(изменить, удалить), но видимо так нельзя делать

Comment: Ну, у QComboBox есть модель, где данные хранятся. Эту модель можно получить и поместить в QListView. Это тот же QListWidget, но без своей модели. Думаю, меняя данные в QListView автоматически поменяете в QComboBox. Так что, можно замутить какую-то кнопку/команду, что покажет QListView, в котором вы уберете, поменяете элементы

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: В чем вопрос? Уже все есть в примерах: Qt-6.2.3/network/fortuneclient/client.cpp